# What is Oracle Session?

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 11g.

I am looking for a good explanation of Oracle Sessions. I googled for this, but strangely, none of the web sites contain any explanation of what oracles sessions are. My specific questions are

1) What are oracle sessions?

2) Does one connection object always relate to one oracle session.?

3) can one oracle session be shared by another connection started by the same user.?

Comment: The Oracle [Documentation Library](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage) is a good place to start.  Check out the Concepts guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A logical entity in the database instance memory that represents the state of a current user login to a database.
2. A single connection can have 0, 1, or more sessions established on it.
3. I can't imagine that it can

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/glossary.htm

Comment: Thanks. How is more than one session on the same connection created?. Suppose I have only one connection object in the pool, and the Stored Procedure takes 5 minutes to finish. If another connection request comes, what will be the behaviour?

Comment: There's more here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:115616585537006::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5671284058977

Comment: How can a connection have more than one session? Can you give me a scenario?

Comment: From the link above you can see this scenario:

> Autotrace for statistics uses ANOTHER session so it can query up the stats for your CURRENT session without impacting the STATS for that session!

But I think in most cases one connection from the app will have just one session.