# how to manage oracle session and odp.net connection object to improve performance of the application?

Tags: c#, oracle

1. How to manage the session in oracle?
2. Is oracle session affect the performance of the database?
3. Is single oracle session can be sharable between different users?
4. Relation between odp.net connection object and oracle session?
5. If connection object is closed in odp.net then session from oracle is also get released?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can monitor and kill sessions, otherwise there is normally no need to manage them. Connecting an user creates one as soon as the first command or query is executed; disconnecting may or may not destroy one (if pooling is involved, it might just idle while the middle tier releases it to the pool); see also
   [What is Oracle Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714328/what-is-oracle-session)
2. The session alone, as such, is not an expensive object and won't have a noticable effect on performance. The transaction volume and query load that is actually executed during a session, will.
3. No. There is the concept of session multiplexing (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc001.htm) but that's about network load optimization.
4. in practice, one connection will correspond to one session. More sessions can be opened during one connection though: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:115616585537006::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5671284058977
5. for all 11g and 12c I worked with using ODP.NET, this was the case. as stated in 1), when pooling is enabled, you may see a number of idle sessions remain for a certain amount of time after all connections in ODP.NET are already closed.